# AJAX Nearly identitcal xmlhttp, one works the other does not?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm having a weird problem...

I inserted an alert here:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert('fine');
    }else {
        alert('fail');
    }
```

Both functions that call the xmlhttp `alert "fail"` but one works while the other does not.

I checked that the serialize was working, and it is, I get the written value in the form.

The php script doesn't show an error... any idea what could be going on? The calls are separate, not called simultaneously, I pretty much replicated the working one for the other call.

This is the full `xmlhttp` function of the working one

```
function insertEntry()
{
var data = $("#entry").serialize();
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert('fine');
    }else {
    alert('fail');
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","write-script.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(data);
clearup();
showSuccess();
}
```

Not working, the alerts go all the way through

```
function insertNote()
{
    alert('clicked');
    var note = $("#note").serialize();
    alert(note);
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    // document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert('fine');
    }else {
    alert('fail');
    }
  }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","write-new-note.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(note);
    alert('done');
}
```

Comment: Can you define "works"?

Comment: inserts into MySQL. I also checked that notes isn't a reserved word.

Comment: var data = $("#entry").serialize(); Are you using jQuery? Why don't you just use the built in Ajax functions?

Comment: Was having problems, this is the way I've gotten to work where I can submit without page refresh. Not saying one is correct/incorrect, I'm just going with what works at this point.

Comment: Use $.ajax() if you're using jQuery. Or use the shorthand functions $.get() and $.post()

Comment: I do notice something interesting, the working one alerts "fail" twice, while the one that isn't working alerts it four times. Both sets of alert result from one click of the submit button for each xmhttp request. It's like the xmlhttp is trying then stops trying after a number of fails.

Comment: @Kaleb Klein, I have used it, I will implement as you suggest to shorten code. Thanks.

Comment: You do know that the readystatechange will be called many times so your "fail" is not really a fail?

Comment: The way I see it if you're using a code base that has an implementation you need, it's best to utilize those resources instead of reinventing the wheel. Unless you need complete and total control, it's not really necessary

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen, I didn't know that.

Comment: I think I figured out what is wrong, I forgot to include the declaration of the variable dt for date time in php.